# how could i generate larger sample that its population?

Tags: python

```
import random

random.sample(range(10,18),100)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-f5d60cc38869>", line 1, in <module>
    random.sample(range(10,18),100)

  File "C:\Users\shamsul\Anaconda3\lib\random.py", line 315, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")

ValueError: Sample larger than population
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample = [random.randrange(10,18) for _ in range(100)]
```

So [obviously you're going to have repeats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), because the sample is larger than the population, but this will give you an evenly distributed sample. Generally a random sample is taking a random subset of a population, so by the usual definition of a sample you can't have a sample that's larger than a population, but if you want just a uniformly distributed list of random numbers in a certain range, this will do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guideence

Comment: how to do it ? I am new in this environment.  I would do anything that would help you. please guide me.

Comment: @ShamsulMasum: Click the check mark icon next to this answer.